# How to enhance ClassCastException message with names of ClassLoader if Class names are equal?

Tags: java, classloader, classcastexception

I am getting a `ClassCastException` because same Class is loaded by different ClassLoaders.

Thus the resulting message of the ClassCastException is not very helpful.

For example: `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl`

Is there a way to enhance the message of the ClassCastException by the names of the both ClassLoaders?

For example: `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@21f67a65[org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:2.7.2(id=64)] cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl loaded by someOtherClassLoader`

The names of the ClassLoaders should only be added if the names of the Classes are equal…

As I am thinking the ClassCastException is created at the internals of JRE?

So the JRE need to be modified?

Do I have to post an enhancement proposal somewhere?

I am not able to get the name of the other ClassLoader by other ways:
• the ClassCastException occurs in foreign code (CXF in this case)
• (remote) debugging via Eclipse does not show the ClassLoader of an instance
• downloading of heap dump would take several hours since problem occurs at remote server

PS: Runtime: `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)`